# A proper class of formulas with every set-sized (but no proper-class-sized) subcollection satisfiable

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

What feature(s) must a (non 1st-order) language with proper-class-many formulas have in order to guarantee that:

There is a proper class P of formulas such that both

(a) every set-sized sub-collection of P is satisfiable, and

(b) no proper-class-sized sub-collection of P is satisifable?

Comment: Do you know of any such class P of formulas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me give a few examples.

**Example 1.** Let us work in Gödel-Bernays set theory, and
assume that $T\subset {}^{<\text{Ord}}2$ is a proper class tree of
height Ord, but there is no cofinal branch.

(This theory is consistent relative to an inaccessible cardinal,
because if $\kappa$ is inaccessible and not weakly compact, then
there is a $\kappa$-Aronszajn tree $T\subset {}^{<\kappa}2$, and
then $V_\kappa$ with all subsets is a model of GBC where $T$ has
the desired property.)

In the logic $L_{\infty,\omega}$, which allows arbitrary sized
conjunctions and disjunctions, with a constant for every element
of $T$ and a unary predicate symbol $B$, consider the theory $P$
consisting of the assertions $\varphi_\alpha$ asserting first,
that there is precisely one object $u$ on level $\alpha$ of the
tree that satisfies $B$, and secondly, that in this case, every
$v<_T u$ also has $B(v)$. These assertions can be made in the
logic $L_{\infty,\omega}$ using constants for the elements of $T$.
Thus, altogether, $P$ is the theory asserting that $B$ is a
cofinal branch through the tree.

Every set-sized subtheory of $P$ mentions only a bounded number of
levels, and so we can find a model by picking any node above that
bound and using the predecessors of that node as the instantiation
of $B$.

But under our assumptions that the tree $T$ is Ord-Aronszajn,
there can be no model of all of $P$ or even of a proper class
sized subtheory of $P$, because any such subtheory will involve
the assertions concerning unboundedly many levels of $T$, and so
the model of that subtheory will pick out a cofinal branch in $T$;
but there is no such branch.

Meanwhile, there is a strong connection between your property and
(non)weak compactness, because an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$
is weakly compact just in case we have the $\kappa$-compactness
property for $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ theories of size $\kappa$. (And
there are diverse variations on this.)

**Example 2.** Here is a different kind of related example using
only first-order logic.

**Theorem.** There is a proper class first-order theory $P$, such
that every set-sized subtheory of $P$ has a model, but no class is
a model of the whole of $P$.

**Proof.** We interpret this as a theorem scheme in ZFC, where by
"class" we mean a definable class (allowing parameters). Thus, I
shall provide a definition of a theory $P$, and then prove first,
that every set-sized subtheory of $P$ is satisfiable, and second,
that no definable class is a model of $P$.

Let $P$ be the theory in the language of set theory $\in$
augmented with a predicate $\newcommand\Tr{\text{Tr}}\Tr$, meant
to serve as a truth-predicate, plus a constant for every object in
the universe. The theory $P$ asserts that $\Tr$ obeys all
instances of the recursive Tarskian truth definition:

- $\Tr(a\in b)$ just in case $a\in b$ holds.
- $\Tr(a=b)$ just in case $a=b$.
- $\Tr(\varphi\wedge\psi)$ just in case $\Tr(\varphi)$ and
  $\Tr(\psi)$.
- $\Tr(\neg\varphi)$ just in case $\Tr(\varphi)$ does not hold.
- $\Tr(\exists x\ \varphi)$ just in case there is $a$ such that
  $\Tr(\varphi(a))$.

For any set many such assertions, we can find a model, since we
can find some $V_\theta$ large enough to contain all the
parameters mentioned in the subtheory, and then use truth in
$\langle V_\theta,\in\rangle$, which will satisfy all the
assertions made in the subtheory.

But no definable class can satisfy $P$, because this is exactly
the content of Tarski's theorem on the non-definability of truth.
**QED**

Meanwhile, this theory $P$ of the theorem does has proper-class
sized subtheories that are satisfiable, since we could, for
example, restrict to the quantifier-free assertions; since there
are so many constants, we can produce proper class trivially
satisfiable subtheories.

Comment: Joel, Thank you! In Example 2's theorem, can "no class is a model of the whole of P" be strengthened to "no class is a model of any class-sized sub theory of P"? Is there a 1st order theory such that no proper-class-sized sub-theory is satisfiable (but every set-sized sub-theory is satisfiable)?

Comment: The first example now has this feature, but the second example has trivial proper class satisfiable subtheories. Perhaps one can modify it.

Comment: @Your first example can be arranged without appeal to the consistency of an inaccessible, since it is known that in every model of ZF + V = HOD there is a definable Ord-tree (a tree of height Ord each proper initial segment of which is a set) which has no definable branches. This follows from one of the main results of the following paper of mine:

Comment: Continuation of my comment (pressed the enter button inadvertantly): https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ali_Enayat2/publications?sorting=newest

Comment: Thanks very much, Ali! But your link takes me to a list of papers, rather than to a single paper. Which do you intend?

Comment: @Joel: oops!  The paper is entitled "Power-like models of set theory" (JSL, 2001)

Comment: I suppose one can make such a tree out of attempts to build a truth predicate---is that how your argument works? That is, a node in the tree should specify the truth values of the first $\alpha$ many formula/parameter pairs, in a way that doesn't yet violate the truth conditions. There is no definable path, because of Tarski's theorem. But we can find arbitrarily high nodes, essentially by the argument of my second example.

Comment: @Joel: your outline is reasonable, but I did it differently because of other goals in my paper: the relevant tree in my paper consists of partial attempts to build a $\Sigma_3$-elementary end extension of the universe; at some point Tarski's undefinability of truth is also used in my argument (after showing that if V has a definable $\Sigma_3$- elementary end extension, it also has one with a first new ordinal).

Comment: I see; very nice! I'll take a look at your paper. In my tree argument, one should insist that the nodes of the tree provide pointers to witnesses for the existential assertions deemed true, whether or not those witnesses appear amongst the first $\alpha$ many parameters. So it is a like a promise that future nodes will have to respect about them, once one gets high enough in the tree.

Comment: It seems to me that one doesn't need V=HOD for this argument, since you can insist that the nodes on level $\alpha$ provide a truth predicate for truth about objects in $V_\alpha$ (but again, where the existential witnesses can point outside of $V_\alpha$. So unless I am mistaken, it seems to me that this shows that every model of ZFC has a definable Ord-tree with no definable branch (allowing parameters).

Comment: @Joel, sounds correct. My use of a global well-ordering was tied to my specific construction, very nice!

Comment: I think I'll write up a blog post about it. I'll post a link here later.

Comment: @Joel: good idea. Every set theorist I have mentioned this result to was surprised; it deserves wider dissemination, especially with your fine-tuning.

Comment: I've realized that the $V\neq\text{HOD}$ case can be alternatively handled as follows: consider the tree of attempts to build a well-ordering of the universe, ordered by extension. That is, nodes of the tree on level $\alpha$ consist of well-ordered enumerations of $V_\alpha$. This is a definable tree with no definable branch, if $V\neq\text{HOD}$, and no branch definable from $p$, if $V\neq\text{HOD}_{\{p\}}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32613/discussion-between-ali-enayat-and-joel-david-hamkins).

Comment: The tree I had in mind with the truth predicate doesn't seem to work out, since the annotations (Skolem witnesses) mean that the levels of the tree will not be sets. Similarly, the tree of attempts to build an elementary Ord-sequence of $V_\theta$'s is also not an Ord-tree, although it can have no definable branch, since this also would give rise to a definable truth predicate. Meanwhile, when global choice fails, the tree of attempts to construct an Ord-enumeration of V does seem to work fine: a definable tree with no definable cofinal branch. So this complements your V=HOD result nicely.

Comment: I cannot get the tree argument to work directly either, but now I can see an easier way of describing a definable Ord-tree whose branches give rise to $\Sigma_n$-elementary end extensions of the universe (for any prescribed fixed $n$), assuming the availability of a parametrically definable global choice function. Given ordinals $\alpha <\beta$, let $M_{\beta, \alpha}$ be the structure $V_\beta$, with constants for each ordinal less than $\alpha$ (continued in the next comment)

Comment: Then consider the tree whose nodes at level $\alpha$ consist of theories of the form $Th(M_{\beta, \alpha})$, where $\alpha$ ranges over ordinals, and $\beta$ ranges over $n$-reflective ordinals above $\alpha$ (the ordering of the tree is set-inclusion).  This tree has no definable branch as a consequence of my result from my paper in JSL 2001 mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: In my previous comment, $Th(M_{\beta, \alpha})$ should be replaced by $Th(M_{\beta, \alpha}, c)$, where $c$ is some element in $V_\beta$ that is above $\alpha$. So each $M_{\beta, \alpha}$ gives rise to many such theories at level $\alpha$ of the tree.

Comment: I had been looking at something very like that, using constants in $V_\alpha$, instead of just $\alpha$, but your idea with $c$ solves a few things, to give rise to the extension. Very nice! I'm going to think it through carefully. I guess if you combine your result with my observation on the tree of attempts to build an Ord-enumeration of V, what we get is that, provably in ZFC, there is a definable Ord-tree with no (parametrically) definable cofinal branch.

Comment: It seems you don't need $c$, since there are plenty of $V_\beta$ with a definable ordinal above $\alpha$, such as:  $c$ is the supremum of the $n$-correct ordinals. If $\beta$ is a (sufficiently large) successor $n$-correct ordinal, then such a definable $c$ will exist in the desired range.

Comment: I completely agree with your comment about the fact that it is provable in ZFC that there are definable Ord-trees without definable branches (by combining my old result and your nice observation).